# I need help with variable expression

Tags: linear-algebra, physics, quadratics

Good day!
I have this coirdinate equation:
$$\frac{gt^2}{2}+{v_y}t-\frac{5}{3}R=0$$
$$v=\sqrt{\frac{10}{9}*gR}$$
How i can express variable $t$ from this equation? 
I calculated this as quadratic equation, and caught this: 
$$t=\sqrt{\frac{10R}{9g}}$$
But on site where i checked result, placed this expression:
$$t=\sqrt{\frac{10}{3}*\frac{R}{g}}*(\frac{\sqrt{10}-1}{3})$$
How to catch this expression?
Exlain me, please. 
Maybe, i have not enough mathematic skills.

Comment: is $v=v_y$ as given?

Comment: Oh, sorry again. I'm not so  attentive. Of course, $v_y=v$

Comment: then you can plug $v_y$ in my formula

Answer (score 0):

this is an equation of the form $$ax^2+bx+c=0$$ the solutions for $x$ are given by
$$x_{1,2}=-\frac{b}{2a}\pm\frac{1}{2a}\sqrt{b^2-4ac}$$ in our example
$$t_1=1/3\,{\frac {-3\,v_{{y}}+\sqrt {30\,gR+9\,{v_{{y}}}^{2}}}{g}}$$
$$t_2=-1/3\,{\frac {3\,v_{{y}}+\sqrt {30\,gR+9\,{v_{{y}}}^{2}}}{g}}$$
solve this formula for $t$:
$$1/2\,g{t}^{2}+1/3\,\sqrt {10}\sqrt {{\frac {R}{g}}}t-5/3\,R=0$$

Comment: Sorry, I forgot expression for variable v. I also caught your final expression, but i can't simplify it.

Comment: use the formula with the given varibles  and simplify it

Comment: Thanks for formula, i'll try to express. But i can't simplify it. I caught $$t_1=\frac{5\sqrt{10R}}{9\sqrt{g}}$$

Comment: i can't read your formula

Comment: Try now, I edited it.

Comment: solve this formula for $t$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32581/discussion-between-ekdown-and-dr-sonnhard-graubner).